# Has anybody tried html2pdf in django?

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdf-generation

Ok when im gonna make reports with Java I use iReport for JasperReports Template designs.

But with python the alternative is [html2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/demo) - pisa.

It would be great to see an example of this.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking about?  Are you asking to see a Django app that calls Java to run Jasper reports?  Why would someone do that when they have ReportLab?

Comment: As iReport is a visual reporting tool for JasperReports (java), what tool is a visual reporting tool for Reportlab?

Comment: @panchicore: Your comment does not match your question at all.  If your comment is correct, could you fix the title of your question.  It's quite hard to reconcile the title, the question and the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accounting software we are developing uses pisa to generate pdf reports. The process is like this:

1. Render a HTML template
2. Convert the rendered string to pdf. You can directly use the HttpResponse object you will return as output file, or a `StringIO` object to store the pdf and send its content via HttpResponse.
3. The mimetype of `HttpResponse` object should be set to `application/pdf` and use `Content-Disposition` header if you want to trigger download instead of displaying in the browser.

Pisa uses some unique CSS properties to specify pdf related formatting (page-size, page-break etc). Their docs provide sufficient examples on this.

Pisa's rendering of HTML/CSS can be quite a bit different from what we usually see in browser. For example, setting `border="1"` on a `<table>` will give all cells of the table border, borders are always collapsed (border-collapse css attribute has no effect) etc.

Comment: Nice touch with the StringIO caching.

Answer (score 3):

And yes, http://www.xhtml2pdf.com comes with a djangoproject example :)

Answer (score 1):

This is written by me, but answers the exact same  questions, so linking it here. http://uswaretech.com/blog/2008/10/generating-pdfs-with-django/